# Constant UFW Block in Syslog

Tags: debian, syslog, ufw

In reviewing my syslog, I've found that 99% of it consists of UFW BLOCK statements from 3 or 4 IP's (see below; edited for space). Is this normal? What do these entries mean? If they are safe, how can I fix or prevent them from being written to the log? In searching this issue it appears that this is somehow related to multicasting, which I know nothing about. I have already tried adding inbound/outbound access for 224.0.0.0/24 for UDP and then restarting UFW to no avail.

UFW Settings

```
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (WWW Full)      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5900/tcp (VNC)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (SSH)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5901                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/16
631 (CUPS)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
224.0.0.0/24/udp           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (WWW Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5900/tcp (VNC (v6))        ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (SSH (v6))          ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5901 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
631 (CUPS (v6))            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
ff02::1/udp                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

224.0.0.0/24/udp           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
ff02::1/udp                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Syslog

```
Jul 22 07:41:07 rpiserver kernel: [200897.130231] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42871 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:41:09 rpiserver kernel: [200898.353921] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30287 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:41:52 rpiserver kernel: [200941.466217] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=58252 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:41:52 rpiserver kernel: [200941.466345] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5859 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:41:53 rpiserver kernel: [200942.487756] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:43:12 rpiserver kernel: [201021.848041] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42872 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:43:19 rpiserver kernel: [201028.200702] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:43:54 rpiserver kernel: [201064.139493] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f0:03:8c:d4:ae:af:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.129 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=58854 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:45:17 rpiserver kernel: [201146.776542] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42873 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:45:18 rpiserver kernel: [201147.390831] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30307 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:45:26 rpiserver kernel: [201155.174401] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12040 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:47:23 rpiserver kernel: [201272.217144] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42874 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:47:28 rpiserver kernel: [201277.951599] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:47:29 rpiserver kernel: [201278.361758] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30319 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:48:15 rpiserver kernel: [201324.953364] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=60685 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:49:27 rpiserver kernel: [201397.151998] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42875 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:49:37 rpiserver kernel: [201406.566453] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:51:11 rpiserver kernel: [201500.980593] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:cc:20:e8:21:ca:c8:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.175 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=27258 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:51:33 rpiserver kernel: [201522.278789] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42876 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:51:35 rpiserver kernel: [201524.329279] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12088 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:53:37 rpiserver kernel: [201647.103024] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42877 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:53:41 rpiserver kernel: [201650.795068] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12102 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:55:42 rpiserver kernel: [201772.033729] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42878 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:55:46 rpiserver kernel: [201775.314779] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12113 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:55:47 rpiserver kernel: [201776.536158] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30372 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:57:47 rpiserver kernel: [201897.166916] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42879 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:57:50 rpiserver kernel: [201899.625495] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12126 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:59:14 rpiserver kernel: [201984.104811] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:cc:20:e8:21:ca:c8:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.175 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=61713 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:59:53 rpiserver kernel: [202022.300223] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42880 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 07:59:55 rpiserver kernel: [202024.754811] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12143 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:01:41 rpiserver kernel: [202130.640971] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5860 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:01:41 rpiserver kernel: [202130.641242] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=13207 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:01:57 rpiserver kernel: [202147.126435] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42881 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:01:58 rpiserver kernel: [202147.331561] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:04:03 rpiserver kernel: [202272.362170] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42882 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:04:06 rpiserver kernel: [202275.229425] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:06:07 rpiserver kernel: [202396.983416] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42883 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:06:08 rpiserver kernel: [202397.190250] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12187 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:07:19 rpiserver kernel: [202468.460367] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:cc:20:e8:21:ca:c8:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.175 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=63754 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:08:13 rpiserver kernel: [202522.321647] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42884 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:08:13 rpiserver kernel: [202522.937013] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:08:16 rpiserver kernel: [202525.598293] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:cc:20:e8:21:ca:c8:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.175 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=17827 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:08:49 rpiserver kernel: [202558.674836] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5861 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:08:50 rpiserver kernel: [202559.288053] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12200 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:09:01 rpiserver CRON[23924]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)
Jul 22 08:09:01 rpiserver CRON[23932]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Jul 22 08:09:03 rpiserver systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Jul 22 08:09:03 rpiserver systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Jul 22 08:10:18 rpiserver kernel: [202647.352331] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42885 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:10:19 rpiserver kernel: [202648.786151] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:10:48 rpiserver kernel: [202677.762409] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:cc:20:e8:21:ca:c8:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.175 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=36218 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:11:31 rpiserver kernel: [202720.261915] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=16506 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:12:05 rpiserver kernel: [202754.567044] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5862 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:12:05 rpiserver kernel: [202754.567170] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12999 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:12:22 rpiserver kernel: [202772.076072] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42886 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:12:23 rpiserver kernel: [202772.278091] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12238 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:14:28 rpiserver kernel: [202897.414683] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42887 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:14:30 rpiserver kernel: [202899.465660] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:16:33 rpiserver kernel: [203022.240598] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42888 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:16:35 rpiserver kernel: [203024.698275] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30490 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:18:38 rpiserver kernel: [203147.375047] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42889 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:18:39 rpiserver kernel: [203148.193364] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12277 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:20:43 rpiserver kernel: [203272.507279] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42890 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:20:43 rpiserver kernel: [203272.711947] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12285 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:22:48 rpiserver kernel: [203397.439781] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42891 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:22:49 rpiserver kernel: [203398.869541] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:24:52 rpiserver kernel: [203521.852334] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42892 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:24:53 rpiserver kernel: [203523.081228] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:26:58 rpiserver kernel: [203647.397325] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42893 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:26:58 rpiserver kernel: [203647.804807] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12327 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:29:03 rpiserver kernel: [203772.426861] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42894 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:29:03 rpiserver kernel: [203772.631665] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30556 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:30:29 rpiserver kernel: [203859.057068] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:cc:20:e8:21:ca:c8:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.175 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=26206 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:07 rpiserver kernel: [203896.839703] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42895 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:10 rpiserver kernel: [203899.706930] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12364 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:22 rpiserver kernel: [203911.794400] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=62194 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:22 rpiserver kernel: [203911.794524] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5863 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:23 rpiserver kernel: [203912.201449] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12368 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:23 rpiserver kernel: [203912.202271] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:31:23 rpiserver kernel: [203912.814213] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=47037 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:32:28 rpiserver kernel: [203978.150212] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:90:8d:6c:17:13:32:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.5 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=62071 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:33:13 rpiserver kernel: [204022.587317] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42896 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:33:14 rpiserver kernel: [204023.611551] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:35:18 rpiserver kernel: [204147.521439] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42897 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:35:22 rpiserver kernel: [204151.615197] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:90:8d:6c:17:13:32:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.5 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=35632 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:37:22 rpiserver kernel: [204271.935530] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42898 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:37:25 rpiserver kernel: [204274.799716] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:38:38 rpiserver kernel: [204347.713070] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5864 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:38:40 rpiserver kernel: [204350.169613] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30614 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:39:28 rpiserver kernel: [204397.683527] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42899 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:39:30 rpiserver kernel: [204400.140961] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30617 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:39:30 rpiserver kernel: [204400.141099] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12402 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:39:42 rpiserver kernel: [204411.205118] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:90:8d:6c:17:13:32:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.5 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=49274 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:41:32 rpiserver kernel: [204521.997460] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42900 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:41:35 rpiserver kernel: [204524.661126] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12847 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:41:35 rpiserver kernel: [204524.661248] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5865 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:41:36 rpiserver kernel: [204525.684204] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12421 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:41:38 rpiserver kernel: [204527.732057] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=38502 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:41:39 rpiserver kernel: [204529.063259] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:90:8d:6c:17:13:32:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.5 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=27427 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:43:37 rpiserver kernel: [204647.028671] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42901 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:43:40 rpiserver kernel: [204649.281249] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12430 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:43:51 rpiserver kernel: [204660.239290] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5866 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:43:52 rpiserver kernel: [204661.876659] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:45:43 rpiserver kernel: [204772.571567] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42902 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:45:43 rpiserver kernel: [204773.185995] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30650 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:47:19 rpiserver kernel: [204868.317446] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:90:8d:6c:17:13:32:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.5 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=17769 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:47:48 rpiserver kernel: [204897.704972] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42903 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:47:52 rpiserver kernel: [204901.592912] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:47:57 rpiserver kernel: [204906.920830] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:90:8d:6c:17:13:32:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.5 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=35773 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:48:00 rpiserver kernel: [204909.584370] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=8008 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:48:00 rpiserver kernel: [204909.584608] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5867 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:48:00 rpiserver kernel: [204909.788286] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12454 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:48:07 rpiserver kernel: [204916.239411] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30670 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:48:56 rpiserver kernel: [204966.007138] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5868 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:48:56 rpiserver kernel: [204966.007266] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=50127 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:49:00 rpiserver kernel: [204970.102163] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=47133 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:49:52 rpiserver kernel: [205021.917343] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42904 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:49:56 rpiserver kernel: [205025.398474] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:51:57 rpiserver kernel: [205146.845289] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42905 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:52:00 rpiserver kernel: [205149.302966] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:54:02 rpiserver kernel: [205271.773877] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42906 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:54:02 rpiserver kernel: [205272.183436] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:30:52:cb:ae:19:48:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.30 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=12497 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:56:08 rpiserver kernel: [205397.316719] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42907 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:56:08 rpiserver kernel: [205397.726255] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:00:1b:b1:89:eb:df:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.36 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=30705 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:58:12 rpiserver kernel: [205521.938216] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42908 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 08:58:15 rpiserver kernel: [205524.600664] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:01 rpiserver kernel: [205630.281934] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=29596 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:01 rpiserver kernel: [205630.282828] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5869 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:01 rpiserver kernel: [205630.685115] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=6762 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:01 rpiserver kernel: [205630.686010] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=5870 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:01 rpiserver kernel: [205630.686921] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:03 rpiserver kernel: [205632.322631] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:46:ce:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.8 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=21906 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:10 rpiserver kernel: [205639.491887] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:fc:d8:48:3c:d0:fb:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.60 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=57480 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:18 rpiserver kernel: [205647.482639] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42909 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:00:19 rpiserver kernel: [205649.119332] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:cf:60:b6:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.140 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:02:23 rpiserver kernel: [205772.512107] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:f4:f5:e8:75:2c:91:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=42910 PROTO=2 
Jul 22 09:02:25 rpiserver kernel: [205774.764880] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:f4:f5:d8:b1:4e:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.11.104 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

Comment: That looks like "normal" multicast network activity - see for example [What could be the cause for these strange UFW block entries in my syslog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278964/what-could-be-the-cause-for-these-strange-ufw-block-entries-in-my-syslog). IIRC it's usually associated with mDNS services such as `bonjour`/`avahi`. See also [What does this firewall record mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67311/what-does-this-firewall-record-mean)

Comment: `ufw logging off`...

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is still experiencing this issue and would like to fix it:

As correctly pointed out by steeldriver in the comment, this is ordinary multicast traffic that you get in most networks, probably caused by some sort of discovery service. To also answer your question with regards to:

> If they are safe, how can I fix or prevent them from being written to the log?

As indicated in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71613/how-can-i-disable-ufw-logging-for-a-specific-event), ufw is logging per rule, whereas it does not log by default. So just create a firewall rule that matches the traffic:

- either explicitly allow this kind of traffic (e.g. by allowing everything to 224.0.0.251 and 224.0.0.1)
- or you explicitly deny this kind of traffic (e.g. by denying everything  to 224.0.0.251 and 224.0.0.1)

Comment: I know you're not responsible for this and this is probably a low-quality comment, but that's so stupid. Why have default routing policies as a feature if `ufw` is going to behave so poorly when it encounters the need for it? If we all have to add a catch-all rule at the end in order for `ufw` to perform sanely then you may as well not even "offer" that feature.

Comment: I can't speak for the developers of ufw, but I personally think the behavior is very reasonable. You typically do a whitelisting by adding only protocols and ports you need and block all other "unexpected" traffic. By logging traffic that is not explicitly defined by a rule, you get important information on what is going on in your network / what is hitting your server. This can be useful for debugging, detecting configuration errors or even attacks. If you find traffic like these multicast requests, you can always add a corresponding rule and logging will stop.

Answer (score -1):

These are the Kernel generated UFW log messages.

In your system a different config file is made for managing these logs,

```
 luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:~$ cd /etc/rsyslog.d/
 luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/etc/rsyslog.d$ ls | grep ufw
 20-ufw.conf
```

See the contents of this file,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/etc/rsyslog.d$ cat 20-ufw.conf 

# Log kernel generated UFW log messages to file
:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log

# Uncomment the following to stop logging anything that matches the last rule.
# Doing this will stop logging kernel generated UFW log messages to the file
# normally containing kern.* messages (eg, /var/log/kern.log)
#& stop
```

Rename this file, and remove the .conf at the end,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/etc/rsyslog.d$ sudo mv 20-ufw.conf 20-ufw
```

Now, restart rsyslog,

```
luvpreet@DHARI-Inspiron-3542:/etc/rsyslog.d$ sudo service rsyslog restart
```

This will stop logging these messages.

NOTE - If you don't see this file, search for this line `:msg,contains,"[UFW " /var/log/ufw.log` in all the files in the folder `/etc/rsyslog.d`. Wherevere you see it, comment this line and restart rsyslog.

Comment: This will indeed stop _all_ UFW-generated messages. I don't think that's a good idea, given two IPs are the issue. Just because the noise from these two IPs drowns out the useful log messages, doesn't mean the whole of UFW messages should be filtered ...